# how to programmaticaly get events from sterling file gateway?

Tags: ibm-sterling

We have Sterling file gateway with UI and everything and we also have control center where we see the file transfers from SFG. Trying to find out how i can subscribe to the events from Filegateway[SFG] programmaticaly. The documentation is not clear on if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The Database tables FG_EVENT and FG_EVENTATTR contain the details about Filegateway events.

Example of SQL query:

```
select * from fg_event t1,fg_eventattr t2 where t1.event_key=t2.event_key and  
event_code='FG_0422'
```

You can add different criteria to the SQL query to filter on filename, type of delivery, date , etc ...

Then you can use SQL queries with any client to query the Database.

Sterling Control Center can monitor the following events:

•Arrived File events - every Sterling File Gateway Arrived File status code is recorded as a successful (FG_0411 - Arrived File Routed) or a failed (FG_0455 - Arrived File Failed) file transfer
•Route events
•Delivery events

More information about [IBM Control Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4Q96_6.1.0/com.ibm.help.scc.monitor.doc/SCC_Viewing_SFG_Activities.html).

There is also another way to invoke business processes by certain events:

Edit the listenerStartup.properties and listenerStartup.properties.in files to include the line:
Listener.Class.xx=com.sterlingcommerce.server1.
 dmi.visibility.event.XpathBPLauncherEventListener

Where xx is the next available number according to how many listeners are already enabled in the file.

Edit the visibility.properties and visibility.properties.in files to add the necessary information to configure the listener to launch the proper business processes based on the correct events. The pattern for registering the events with the listener is:
bp_event_trigger.X=eventPreFilter,xPathExpression,bpname,userId

There is an example in this page:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3JSW_5.2.0/com.ibm.help.aft.doc/SI_AFT_InternalEvent.html